# Functions satisfying a minimal total variation for a power unity.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Inspired by this [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512780/how-to-build-smooth-families-of-functions-satisfying-a-power-unity/2513144#2513144) which ended up allowing much laxer solutions than I intended.

If we want to find

$$\min_{f_k}\left\{\sum_{k=0}^n \int_{\mathcal I} \left|\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial t}\right|dt\right\}$$

But with the extra constraint:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {f_k}(t)^m = 1$$

I don't know if the pair $\{\sin(kt),\cos(kt)\}$ solves it any longer.

Wait, this would allow one function to be constant $1$ and the others $0$. That's not very interesting. We need one more constraint. What about this boundary condition one?

$$\cases{f_k(0) = x_k\\f_k(1) = y_k}$$

Obviously we will need $$\cases{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n {x_k}^m = 1\\\\\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n {y_k}^m = 1}$$

But at least we can select $x_k \neq y_k$ and therefore make sure the constant functions are no longer a solution.